# how can i pass a useState hook defined with typescript down to another react component?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, use-state

#### I am having some difficulties passing down a useState hook down from one component to another component using Typescript

Here is a very simple code that has only two files to show this problem:

**the App component which is the entry point of the example**

```js
import { useState } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Header from './Components/Header';

type personType = {
 name: String,
 language: String
}

const initialPerson ={
 name : 'james',
 language: 'english'
} 

function App() {
 const [ person, setPerson] = useState<personType>(initialPerson);

 return (
   <div className="App">
     <Header setPerson={setPerson} person={person}/>
   </div>
 );
}

export default App;
```

**the Header component that receives the useState as props**

```js
import { personType } from "../../App"

const Header = ({person, setPerson}:{person: personType, setPerson:any}) => {

  const handleTranslate = () => {
    setPerson({name:'john', language:'french'})
  }
  return(
    <div>
      <h1>TYPESCRIPT TEST</h1>
      <button onClick={handleTranslate}>clickMe</button>
      {person.name}
      {person.language}
    </div>
  )
}

export default Header
```

Now i am having trouble redefining the useState function 'setPerson' i am leaving it to :any for now because i can't seem to be able to find the right syntax in the there for the function argument.

i have tried :

```js
 setPerson:(personType)=> personType
```

the return type is fine, it is the argument that i cannot find the syntax for...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First export your type **personType** so that it can be accessible in other components. Either export it from same component or export it from another typescript file just like below.

```
export type personType = {
  name: String;
  language: String;
};
```

Then you have to import this type in **Header** Component

```
import React, {  useState, FC } from "react";
import { personType } from "../App";
type IHeaderProps = {
  person: personType;
  setPerson: (person: personType) => void;
};
const Header: FC<IHeaderProps> = ({ person, setPerson }) => {
  const handleTranslate = () => {
    setPerson({ name: "john", language: "french" });
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>TYPESCRIPT TEST</h1>
      <button onClick={handleTranslate}>clickMe</button>
      {person.name}
      {person.language}
    </div>
  );
};
```

You need to just define what props type the **Header** component will receive. In our case one is **person** of type **personType** and second is **function**
I just test it and it is working perfect. I hope this will answer your question. If it does, then please check the icon to mark it as accepted answer.

Thanks !

Comment: oh thanks so much ! i get it now i see where i was wrong and got confused !! all good thanks again !

Comment: You are always welcome

Answer (score 1):

Another answer is "fine" in most cases, however, sometimes you will need the callback from useState, e.g:

```
setPerson(prevPerson => ({ ...prevPerson, name: "Rick" }))
```

So, the correct type would be:

```
type IHeaderProps = {
    person: personType;
    setPerson: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<personType>>
};
```